# Apex Rest API POST multipart/form-data get no file parts in upload

Tags: apex, rest-api, apexrest, omnichannel

I used Apex REST API to send data to OCI to update availability, but receive 400-Bad Request with response data:

```
{
  "errorCode" : "Unknown",
  "message" : "No file parts in upload"
}
```

This is my code logic to send data to OCI:

```
String apiEndpoint = 'https://{shortCode}.api.commercecloud.salesforce.com/inventory/impex/v1/organizations/{organizationId}/availability-records/imports/uploadlink/{uploadLinkId}';
// Set up a request
String boundary = '--' + String.valueOf(DateTime.now().getTime());
String header = boundary + '\nContent-Disposition: form-data; ';
header += 'name="ImportsUploadLinkPostBody";\n\n';
String requestBodyString = '{"recordId": "1", "onHand": "100", "sku": "GC1020", "effectiveDate": "2024-01-30T08:59:50.452Z", "futures": [{"quantity": 100, "expectedDate": "2024-01-30T08:59:50.452Z"}], "locationId": "Warehouse01"}
{"recordId": "2", "onHand": "99", "sku": "GC1060", "effectiveDate": "2024-01-30T08:59:50.453Z", "futures": [{"quantity": 99, "expectedDate": "2024-01-30T08:59:50.453Z"}], "locationId": "Warehouse01"}';
String footer = boundary + '--';
String bodyPayload = header + requestBodyString + footer;

HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint(apiEndpoint);
request.setMethod('POST');
request.setHeader('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data; boundary=' + boundary);
request.setHeader('Content-Length', String.valueOf(bodyPayload.length()));
request.setHeader('Authorization', bearerToken);
request.setBody(bodyPayload);

Http http = new Http();
HttpResponse response = http.send(request);
String responseBody = response.getBody();
String status = response.getStatus();
Integer statusCode = response.getStatusCode();
```

Please help to support if I have any issue in my logic.
Document to refer:

- https://docparser.com/blog/post-file-salesforce-apex-external-http-webservices/
- https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/commerce/commerce-api/references/impex?meta=postUploadImportFile